# How to iterate the value of an index in a list using an integer

Tags: python, list

```
class Planet:
    def __init__(self, name, radius, system, gravity):
        self.name=name
        self.radius=radius
        self.gravity=gravity
        self.system=system

    def orbit(self):
        return(f'{self.name} is orbiting in the {name} system')

planet_list=[]

while True:
    name = input('Enter the Planet\'s name: \n')
    radius = int(input('Enter the Planet\'s radius: \n'))
    gravity = int(input('Enter the Planet\'s gravity: \n'))
    system = input('Enter the Planet\'s system: \n')
    sub_list=[name,radius,gravity,system]

    planet_list.append(sub_list)

    again=input('\nAdd another planet? (Y/N): ')
    if again.startswith('y') or again.startswith('Y'):
        continue
    elif again.startswith('n') or again.startswith('N'):
        break
    else:
        print('I didn\'t quite catch that...')
        continue

def planet_intro(dictionary):
     for world in planet_list:
        i=0
        print(f'\nPlanet: {planet_list[i][0]}\nRadius: {planet_list[i][1]}\nGravity: {planet_list[i][2]}\nSystem: {planet_list[i][3]}\n')
        i+=1

planet_intro(planet_list)
```

I've been at this for a while, but for whatever reason, I cannot declare an integer and use that variable as the value for an index. I literally just jumped into Java today, so this could be a very simple fix that's gone over my head, but I've yet to figure it out.

So if I run this, it repeats the same data for however many lists are in `planet_list`, without iterating the value of the index (changing the data printed).

Comment: Why do you need the index? You can just use `world`, no? To iterate over the indices, use `range`, to iterate over the elements and indices together, use `enumerate`

Comment: While the others are correct, and those are the ways I would iterate over a list in Python, your problem is that you're setting i to 0 at every step of your iteration. So your print statement will always see i as 0, then it'll get incremented to 1, but immediately set back to 0 when the loop restarts.

Answer (score 2):

Your iteration is a little incorrect.

Use:

```
def planet_intro(planet_list):
     for world in planet_list:
        print(f'\nPlanet: {world[0]}\nRadius: {world[1]}\nGravity: {world[2]}\nSystem: {world[3]}\n')
```

Comment: Change `dictionary` to `planet_list`

Comment: @JoePatten. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your print statements are the same is that you need to take the `i=0` outside of the loop (as each time you loop, you are resetting your `i` to `0`). Also, you should be taking in as input `planet_list`

```
def planet_intro(planet_list):
     i=0
     for world in planet_list:
        print(f'\nPlanet: {planet_list[i][0]}\nRadius: {planet_list[i][1]}\nGravity: {planet_list[i][2]}\nSystem: {planet_list[i][3]}\n')
        i+=1
```

You could also use enumerate to iterate over the items of the list and have an index. Your code would like:

```
def planet_intro(planet_list):
     for i, world in enumerate(planet_list):
        print(f'\nPlanet: {planet_list[i][0]}\nRadius: {planet_list[i][1]}\nGravity: {planet_list[i][2]}\nSystem: {planet_list[i][3]}\n')
```

But I still think that Rakesh has the best code, so I would go with his.